# Asynctask for cycle and substring

Tags: android, android-asynctask, substring, cycle

i'm developing a livescore app: i'm using an asynctask in which in the doInBackground function I download the data from the web and elaborate them. In the doInBackground there is a for cycle, and inside it there is a substring istruction.
The problem is that, with the substring istruction the for cycle doesn't run all the cycles (makes 50 instead 100+ cycles). If I remove the substring istruction it runs all the cycles perfectly.
Can anyone help me? (sorry for bad english)

Comment: at least copy&paste your code here

Comment: cycle ? like a `while` or `for` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int i=0;
        String casa=null;
        String trasferta=null;
        String Ris=null;
        String hinizio=null;



        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URLind)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                    .timeout(60000).get();

            Elements partite = doc.select(....);
            Elements Competizioni = doc.select(....);
            String comp=Competizioni.toString();
            String Competizione=null;
            if(ObjPartita.size()==0){


                for (i=0;i<=partite.size();i++){

                   //Some Jsoup Query
                    //ObjPartita.add(new Partita....)
                    Competizione=EstraiCampionato(comp,trasferta); //EstraiCampionato is a function that manipulate some String (substring, indexOf and conditions...)

                }


            }else{
                //Other Jsoup Query
                }

            }






        } catch (Exception e) {
            // gestione dell'eccezione
            // ad esempio mostrare messaggio di errore o altro (qui nel logcat)
            //Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that if I remove the "EstraiCampionato" function, the for cycle completes all the cycles perfectly. Contrarily, with the "EstraiCampionato" function it runs only a part of the cycle (for example 50 instead of 100+)